# Maven-3.3.9 pulling dependencies always from remote not from Local

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am migrating from Maven-3.0.X to Maven-3.3.9 as to adapt the recent surefire plugin releases.

But the problem am facing is during this migration, i found Maven is always pulling the dependencies from remote not from the local even we have the repositories available in the local.  I hope Maven will initially look up for local, if the dependencies NA then will pull out the remote.

Note

1) I am able to force my maven to do an offline build [-o] or passing the -Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true to work which i do not want to implement.

2) Tried with UpdatePolicy="never" option, but no luck

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Test Application</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Error log

```
Downloading from repo.nexus: http://127.0.0.1:9080/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-esb-maven-plugins/1.7/mule-esb-maven-plugins-1.7.pom
Downloading from jfrog: http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-esb-maven-plugins/1.7/mule-esb-maven-plugins-1.7.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.7 @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test:TEST_PROJECT:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/usr/local/TEST_PROJECT/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.7: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-esb-maven-plugins:pom:1.7 from/to jfrog (http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local): Connect to repo.jfrog.org:80 [repo.jfrog.org/52.7.30.14, repo.jfrog.org/34.231.202.145] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

I expect Maven to refer the local first and then the remote as this is the way it worked before in Maven-3.0.X.

Comment: Did you try updatePolicy="never" in your <pluginRepository> config?

Comment: First how are you calling Maven? Are you running on command line? Or are you running within a CI solution like Jenkins? And yes check your updatePolicy ? Furthermore Please show an example pom file? Are you using version ranges?

Comment: Yes, tried with updatePolicy="never" also, no luck.

Comment: And its from Jenkins CI mode only and no version ranges used.  will share the pom shortly.

Comment: Added the pom.xml.

Comment: You are hiding the error but Maven tries first to download update of the POM files. Are you sure your are not misreading the error ? (which, again, is hidden and supposed to be "failed to download whatever").

Comment: @NoDataFound - Added the exact error.  See that, org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7 creating the problem whereas i have that dependencies on my local.  This is what my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to build your sample `pom.xml` with Maven 3.3.9 (and 3.6.0): there are no `com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core:3.6.0:jar`; closest seems to be `org.mule:mule-core:3.6.0`.

If the POM of said dependency was not found, Maven will issue a warning and store a `.lastUpdated` file. The file contains a time stamp indicating when the error was issued for some repository.

When *some time* passed between two executions or if `-U` is used, Maven will retry downloading the dependency (or its POM). I think that's where you got your error.

The POM is not mandatory for Maven, it issue a warning:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core:jar:3.6.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

However, when it tries to download it, it must at least work up to some `404 NOT FOUND`: I used some local unbound IP and this failed too:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Application 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://192.168.113.145/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core/3.6.0/mule-core-3.6.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.336 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-27T20:04:11+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com:test:mule:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core:jar:3.6.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core:jar:3.6.0: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core:pom:3.6.0 from/to bintray (https://192.168.113.145): Connect to 192.168.113.145:443 [/192.168.113.145] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

This error is not the same as yours, but that at least more or less explain why Maven go for the remote.

There are other cases:

- Maven will try to download plugin metadata from repositories if the plugin/dependency does not have an explicit version (this means "take the latest", perhaps in limited range [eg: version of maven, transitive dependency..., ). Default plugin, such as `maven-clean-plugin`, are fixed by the version of Maven.
- You use `SNAPSHOT` version and Maven will fetch the latest (unless disabled in your `<repository>`)

That being said, I think your problem (your question) is the wrong one:

> But the problem am facing is during this migration, I found Maven is
>   always pulling the dependencies from remote not from the local even we
>   have the repositories available in the local.

The fact that Maven is failing because it could not find the dependency remotely means that, in your configuration, your build will not work on another machine:

1. Your Nexus repository (http://127.0.0.1:9080/nexus) is not storing the dependency meaning it fails its purpose (having a enterprise repository is to cut from problems from outside, first of them being removal or replacement).
2. It should not be in `127.0.0.1` but on a separate server unless your proxy an enterprise repository to your localhost for other reasons; at least, it should be backup-ed.
3. Your `settings.xml` should use a mirror to that repository (if you want to be sure that your don't download dependencies/plugin from external source).

In particular, if you change the local repository (for example, pointing `<localRepository>` to `~/.m2/repository.fresh`), the build should not fail due to those missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this really helps.  yes, I am mirroring the repo from the public with my local nexus repo.  Apologize if I am repeating, but when I do simple switch to old maven version then I am able to build it whereas failing when I am using 3.3.9.  If it refreshes the repo, then the same behavior would be there in both the versions, but this is not the case.

Comment: What's strange here, is that I could download the plugin and dependency without problems. You should try a mvn -X and check what Maven is really doing. You may also try, `mvnDebug` and remote debugging with a breakpoint to the method doing the `throw new XX` error. There might be an hidden error (like a `catch (Exception e) {throw new OtherException("Dependency failed"); }`)

Comment: Error got after the debug enabled.  Exploring more now -  


Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-esb-maven-plugins:pom:1.7 from/to jfrog (http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local): Connect to repo.jfrog.org:80 [repo.jfrog.org/52.7.30.14, repo.jfrog.org/34.231.202.145] failed: Connection timed out

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.7

Comment: Are you behind some proxy ? Because using your pom I could certainly connect.

Comment: Yes, I will come back quickly.

Comment: proxy was the problem and rectified now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome (and welcome to the jungle of damn proxies :P)